# SVN disappeared from Android Studio - Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, svn, android-studio

After a forced shutdown in MacOS SVN simply disappeared from my Android Studio. I tried unstalling, and installing again from a newly downloaded file, but SVN doesn't seem to want to work with me today.

I have no idea what to do, since, until now, SVN worked right from the box, with no configuration needed at all.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

After hitting my head on walls for a couple of hours I figured out what was wrong. It seems that, when crashing, Android Studio (i.e. Intellij) disabled the SVN plugin.

Somehow that definition survived a reinstall and even running straing from a newly downloaded file, but to fix it it was just a case of going to Plugin Preferences and enabling the SVN plugin.

/The More you Know/

Answer (score 0):

This link was helpful to get me going (OSX 10.1.1, Android Studio 1.3.2, svn via HomeBrew) http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/how-to-upgrade-subversion-on-osx/